# DL185 G5 poor Ethernet lan speed

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, wired-networking

I picked up this server for like $20 and just using it for my homelab setup.  The problem is that the ethernet speeds are peaking at 8MB/s on the LAN and even worse to the internet down to like 5MB/s.  This would normally point to being connected at 100Mbps but both server and router are reporting a 1000Mbps link.  This is both pulling to server and pushing out which rules out drive speeds.  Plus testing on SSD.  My computer will do gigabit speeds connected to same router.  I have used the same cable on the server with no change.  Running Proxmox on Debian with kernel 5.3.18-2-pve.  Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

ethtool:

```
Settings for enp2s2f0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
        Link detected: yes
```

lspci:

```
Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Iperf:

```
    [  5] local 192.168.0.210 port 5201 connected to 192.168.0.10 port 53443
    [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
    [  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  4.88 MBytes  4.87 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  4.96 MBytes  4.96 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  5.44 MBytes  5.44 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  5.50 MBytes  5.50 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  5.49 MBytes  5.49 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  5.41 MBytes  5.41 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  5.20 MBytes  5.20 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  5.17 MBytes  5.17 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  5.40 MBytes  5.40 MBytes/sec
    [  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  5.16 MBytes  5.16 MBytes/sec
    [  5]  10.00-10.06  sec   280 KBytes  4.37 MBytes/sec
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
    [  5]   0.00-10.06  sec  52.9 MBytes  5.25 MBytes/sec                  receiver

&#x200B;
```

I can run this for however long I want but this is exactly the same issue.  I seems like somehow is locking to 100mbps no matter what the router and server say link speed is

Comment: My first guess would be drivers. I'd like to see iPerf benchmarks to ensure it's not something wrong with your drive or another piece of software.

Comment: Added iperf results.  Doesn't matter how long I run it, number never goes above 5MB/s

Comment: Even if the connection was (physically) limited to 100Mbps Ethernet I would expect speeds to be much higher than 5 MB/s.

Comment: Yeah I'm at a loss at this point.  Don't even know where to go further with troubleshooting

Comment: @JamesTaylor I've seen similar issues due to outdated/incompatible drivers. Is it possible for you to see about updating the NIC drivers?